# Why is DATEDIFF parsing these dates as dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: sql, datediff

I do:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(month, Convert(datetime,'01/10/2018',103), 
       Convert(datetime,'30/04/2019',103)) AS 'Month1', 
       DATEDIFF(month, '10/01/2018','04/30/2019') AS 'Months2', 
       DATEDIFF(month, '10/02/2018','05/01/2019') AS 'Months3'
```

Please show me why it return 6,6,7?

Comment: What's your dbms? I think you are using sqlserver You need to take a look  https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Just use standard formats for dates -- YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

here date format is day month year

```
 DATEDIFF(month, Convert(datetime,'01/10/2018',103), 
           Convert(datetime,'30/04/2019',103)) AS 'Month1'
```

so difference of 10 month(october) and 4(april) month =6

below code date format is month day year

```
DATEDIFF(month, '10/01/2018','04/30/2019') AS Months2,
```

so again 10(october) and 4(april) month difference is 6

and the 3rd date format is like 2nd

```
DATEDIFF(month, '10/02/2018','05/01/2019') AS Months3
```

so difference between 10(october) 2018 and may(5) 2019 is 7

As a result your query showing output 6,6,7

Answer (score 0):

The first 6 is the difference (in months) between 01/10/2018 (October 1, 2018) and 30/04/2019 (April 4, 2019). The CONVERT call is to force the second date to be parsed using date format 103 (i.e. British/French, i.e. dd/mm/yyyy), which makes me suspect that your SQL implementation is set up to parse them as some other format (e.g. US: mm/dd/yyyy).

The second 6 is the difference (in months) between 10/01/2018 (October 1, 2018) and 04/30/2019 (April 30, 2019).

The 7 is the difference (in months) between 10/02/2018 (October 2, 2018) and 05/01/2019 (May 1, 2019). The fact that these dates *could* be parsed as Feb 10 and Jan 5, but aren't, confirms that your SQL implementation is parsing dates in mm/dd/yyyy format.

If you are really passing dates as strings, I  recommend using an unambiguous format (e.g. "October 1, 2018"), as it will make the code clearer, and less brittle.